# Concatenation of arraylist separated by comma

Tags: java

i have a requirement to parse the xml data which have the repeated elements and  concatenate all the arraylist separated by comma.

i want the o/p string like john,john1,john2,john3,john4 but i am getting my output:         ,     John,   , John1,   , John2,   , John3,   , John4,

```
 package eclipsepackage;
 import javax.xml.parsers.*;
 import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
 import org.w3c.dom.*;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.ArrayList;


public class xmlparserclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xmlRecords =
              "<data>" +
              " <service_add>" +
              "  <service_cd>John</service_cd>" +
              "  <service_cd>John1</service_cd>" +
              "  <service_cd>John2</service_cd>" +
              "  <service_cd>John3</service_cd>" +
              "  <service_cd>John4</service_cd>" +
              " </service_add>" +
              "</data>";

            try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
                    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

                Document doc = db.parse(is);

                NodeList nPanList = doc.getElementsByTagName("service_add"); 

                for(int temp = 0 ; temp <nPanList.getLength(); temp++){ 
                Node nNode = nPanList.item(temp); 
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode; 
                NodeList childList = eElement.getChildNodes(); 
                String [] sPANNO = new String[childList.getLength()] ; 
                ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                for(int i = 0; i < childList.getLength(); i++){ 
                Node childNode = childList.item(i); 
                list.add(childNode.getTextContent());                   
                } 

                if (list.size() >= 1) {
                    System.out.print(list.get(0));
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) { 
                     System.out.print(", " + list.get(i));
                }
              } 

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure the text elements which you have stored in the ArrayList don't contain any commas already ?

Comment: Thanks, i realized that there are some spaces in my text it self.

Answer (score 0):

i removed spaces after the double quotes then it worked. All the text elements are concatenated separated by comma.